# Can't get armatures to work with loop cuts on mesh

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

[image]

I want to make the armatures on my mesh to bend the arms at their loop cuts, but when I do, even though the bone joints are in exact same place as the loop cuts, it moves the arms as so: [image]
Here's the file.[image]

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give the blend file ... from the look of it, upper arm bone is not attached to arm and arm bone is totally controlling the whole arm  mesh.

Comment: No, the upper arm bone works, it's just that when one arm bone moves, it takes control of the whole arm. But how do I give you the blend file?

Comment: look at https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/where-to-upload-blend-files-non-expiring-links for upload

Comment: If you add a loop cut or edit the armature after you parent the armature to the mesh you will need to adjust the weight painting, or re-do the parent to armature.

Comment: Thanks, sambler. That helped me out a lot, and it should go down to be an answer.